# How to check a specific format using regex in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have dates in my excel file in the following format MM/DD/YYYY

I am going through worksheet using for each loop and getting value by cell.Value

I'd like to check whether currently processed cell is in the above format and if so, change it to YYYY-MM-DD ( database format )

Can I do this in VBA ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Those are real dates or dates as strings? I asked this because Excel treats dates as numbers so how you see a date in a cell is due to the formatting while there is a number underneath the date. To check if the date is real date not a date string, assuming you have date in A2, then in any blank cell type the formula `=ISNUMBER(A2)`. A2 contains a real date if the formula returns `True` else it is a date string.

Answer (score 1):

**Without Regex:**

```
Sub DateTest()
    With ActiveCell
        If IsDate(.Value) And .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" Then
            .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

*NOTE:*

If the values are `Strings`, changing the `NumberFormat` will have no visible effect on the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeDateFormats()
    Dim thisCell As Range
    For Each thisCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Debug.Print thisCell.NumberFormat
        If thisCell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" Then
            thisCell.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        End If
    Next thisCell
End Sub
```